# Deleting Div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, closest

Here is my Code

```
<div class="k-top">  
  <span class="k-in">Module = UserManagement</span>
</div>

<ul class="k-group">
   <li class="k-item">
     <div class="k-top">
         <span class="k-in">Forms = Manage Users</span>
     </div>
         <ul class="k-group" >
             <li id="treeview_tv_active">
                <div class="k-top">
                       <span class="k-state-selected k-in">Tasks = Modify</span>
                </div>

               <ul class="k-group">
                     <li class="k-item" >
                         <div class="k-top">   //I want to delete This DIV
                           <span class="k-in">Roles = User, Admin, Approver</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="k-item k-last" >
                        <div class="k-bot">
                           <span class="k-in">Roles = User,Admin,</span>
                         </div>
                   </li>
              </ul>
         </li>
```

I have tried the following jQuery

```
$('.k-in').closest('.k-top').remove();
```

to delete follwing div

```
<div class="k-top">   
     <span class="k-in">Roles = User, Admin, Approver</span>
 </div>
```

but this is deleting all the divs with `class ="k-top"`

How can i delete the particular div from the above code

Please help me to solve this

Comment: When do you want it to be removed? `$('.k-in')` selects all elements with `k-in` class.

Comment: Yes, you need something to distinct all the 'k-in' or 'k-in' divs...

Comment: @Mathew By clicking on `<span class="k-state-selected k-in">Tasks = Modify</span>` I want to delete `<div class="k-top">` or `<span class="k-in">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have multiple dividers with the class "k-in". The selector you're using pulls all 5 of the "k-in" class elements then finds the closest element with a class of "k-top" (in each case this is their parent apart from the very last one), then removes them all.

If you want to specifically remove only one of those dividers you can give it a unique identifier and select on that:

```html
<ul class="k-group" >
         <li id="treeview_tv_active">
            <div class="k-top">
                   <span class="k-state-selected k-in" id="k-in-3">Tasks = Modify</span>
            </div>

    <ul class="k-group">
         <li class="k-item" >
            <div class="k-top">   //I want to delete This DIV
                   <span class="k-in" id="k-in-4">Roles = User, Admin, Approver</span>
             </div>
         </li>
         ...
```

Calling:

```js
$('#k-in-4').closest('.k-top').remove();
```

Comment: I am using Kendo UI, I cant edit the class name as i'm getting this from kendo only

Comment: In that case you're going to have to do a bit of a crazy selector. In this case, something like `$('.k-group').find('.k-group').find('.k-group').find('.k-top').remove();`. This selects the `.k-top` element contained within a `.k-group` element contained within another `.k-group` element contained within yet another `.k-group` element, then removes it.

Comment: this one did the trick `$('#treeview_tv_active').find('.k-group').find('.k-top').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$('li ul.k-group .k-item:first-child').remove();`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLHbj/)

**EDIT:**

Try this one :

`$('.k-group .k-item .k-group .k-group .k-item:first-child .k-top').remove();`

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLHbj/1/)

Comment: it is deleting all the class with k-group

Comment: Am getting same prob, it is again  deleting all the divs

Comment: @speeday125 you sure you checked the **Updated Demo** link? Because it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, `$('.k-group .k-group .k-item .k-group .k-group .k-item:first-child .k-top').remove();` I'm having another k-group which i forgot to paste in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
$('.k-in:contains("Roles = User, Admin, Approver")').parent('.k-top').remove();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/336SX/.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to give an ID to the div you want to remove and try the following:

```
$('#divID').remove();
```

Class selector will return too many elements as many elements are having the same class with almost similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

I started from the root to delete the div

```
$( 'ul li ul li ul li div.k-top').remove();
```

note li tag associated with the div (that was deleted) still remains. To get rid of the li, you can use this version instead:

```
$( 'ul li ul li ul li:first').remove();
```

it still works if you omit the first ul tag (root)

```
$( 'li ul li ul li:first').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to remove the element?

If it's on element click you could do something like:

```
$('.k-in').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.k-top').remove();
});
```

If from any where else than you have to have an id or other atribute/property associated to filter the choice, as @James Donnelly jQuery will get all occurrences for:

```
$('.k-in).closest('.k-top').remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following

```
$('.k-in').parent().remove();
```

If you have k-top the immediate parent of this span